# sysbench with SSL?

Tags: mysql, ssl, benchmarking

Has anyone tried benchmarking MySQL with sysbench using the "mysql-ssl" option?

I can't figure out where sysbench looks for the client key, client certificate, and ca cert. You can find the sysbench manual here (http://sysbench.sourceforge.net/docs/), but it doesn't have any mention of the location of the certificate files.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I got it figured out. If sysbench is started with the "**--mysql-ssl=on**" option, it looks in the current directory for the following files:

**client-cert.pem**
**client-key.pem**
**cacert.pem** (note no dash)

Hope this helps other confused sysbench-ers.

Chris